# OR in dataframe select expression

Tags: r, dataframe, data.table

```
DF1 <- DF[DF$cat == 'A', ]
DF2 <- DF[DF$cat == 'B', ]
RDF <- rbind(DF1, DF2)
```

Is there a way to express this in a more straightforward way, such as

```
RDF <- DF[DF$ cat == c('A','B'), ] # Does not work
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
RDF <- DF[DF$cat %in% c('A','B'), ]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use data.table and keys

```
library(data.table)
DT <- data.table(DF)
setkey(DT, cat)

DT[c("A", "B"),]
```

Answer (score 1):

More generally, for two conditions:

```
RDF <- DF[ DF$cat == "A" | DF$dog == "B", ]
```

Comment: Minor point: that repeats the variable name `DF` twice. See here for the issue: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10758086/403310.